# Changing the color of bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is straight from the bootstrap site's page. In this certain code i would like to know how to change  the color of the text from blue to black. It is by default blue at the moment.

Site for reference and a live example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/
Code: The section the code is under is called "Using Drop downs" Tabs with drop downs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  ...
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Regards

Comment: you mean http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns ?

Comment: exactly what you want to do ?change the color of button back-ground or drop down text color?

Comment: i want to change the color of the text and the dropdown symbol to black. Not the actual background color of the button.

Comment: why don't you just change the css using the defaults as references? copy the defaults and alter the color. or adding a new class name and use that to style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can apply custom style on class "dropdown-toggle" in your css file

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: using `!important` is not recommended as it will override any newer intended styling without `!important`

Comment: use id on li and apply in this way: example<li id ="abc"</li>     #abc .dropdown-toggle {
    color: black;
}   so it will take only for those drop-down-toggle class which has id "abc" and remove the !important from style

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap dropdown buttons are like other bootstrap buttons. A default bootstrap button has the `btn` class.

You can change their themes by adding classes such as `btn-primary`, `btn-info`, `btn-danger`, etc.

For more examples of this check out http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns.

Comment: More importantly, a default Bootstrap button has the `btn-default` class

Answer (score 1):

use id on li and apply style in this way: example

```
<li id ="abc"</li>
```

Custom Style

```
#abc .dropdown-toggle {
    color: black;
}
```

so it will take only for those drop-down-toggle class which has id "abc" and remove the !important from style